# Rails - Sending a parameter with link_to with nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to send a parameter through link_to and I'm not sure of how to access it... or if I'm even doing this correctly.

My routes are set up as follows:

```
resources :coins do
  resources :questions
end
```

From the coin page, each link creates a new question and is supposed to include a value, ques_num, which is an an integer from 1 to 5. This number corresponds to a question number. So the first link sends :ques_num = 1, the second sends :ques_num = 2, etc. I want to access this number and store it in @question.ques_num. How do I do this?

I'm currently creating the links and attempting to send the parameter with:

```
<%= link_to "Submit an answer", new_coin_question_path(@coin.id, :ques_num => 1) , class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

I see that the correct parameters show up in the URL (The first link produces URL: http://localhost:3000/coins/1/questions/new?ques_num=1 )

How can I access this value from the new_coin_question_path that it redirects to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question directly, I believe you're looking for `params[:ques_num]` or `params.fetch(:ques_num)`.

More generally, I'd recommend looking into building out your debugging strategies. A runtime console (such as [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry)) can greatly help you gain context when you're not sure what you have access to.

Comment: That was it. Thank you. Thanks for the Pry suggestion. I'm brand new to Rails and will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting this right, the problem is that you are passing the parameter on the method that renders the view, where the form to create the question is, where it is needless. You can add a hidden input value in the form of the `question_num` and pass it also to the controller on the method that **creates** the question.

## Caution

If you want your questions to be accessed with their `question_num` parameter in their own view that's another issue and you need to set your own routes in order to achieve it. Rails default routes work with ids which means that you 'll get something like: `/coins/1/questions/10` where 10 is the question id, when trying to see the `questions#show` view.

Comment: Actually the parameter is passed to the page that renders the view. It comes from the Coin page which has 5 links to 5 questions and no form (so I don't think I can use a hidden field).  This number passed is also not used as an ID, I just need it for the questions.

Comment: I am sorry but it seems I still don't understand the case! The link you provided in the question `http://localhost:3000/coins/1/questions/new?ques_num=1 ` looks like you want to create a new `Question.new`. What method are you calling in your `link_to`?